# Image preview OK with Windows Image Viewer, but why browser is unable to render it?

Tags: image-processing, browser, broken-image

I have some images which I can view using Windows Image Viewer or Microsoft Office 2010 or Paint 3D, but somehow browser is not able to render the image and showing square box with a cross. Please check the images below

```
Image preview in Microsoft Office 2010
```

[image]

```
Image preview in Chrome Browser (Same issue with every browser)
```

[image]

Chrome console screenshot:

[image]

[image]
Please help if you have any clue about the possible reasons.

Thanks,

Comment: must have error messages in console, that might help

Comment: @JayLi no errors in console. I have updated my answer with screenshot of chrome's console.